# IOException while playing the music using media player

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to play a song using the `Uri`. I'm using media player to play the song but I'm getting IOException.

```
 try{
                String url = "http://stream6.infotraxsys.com/conference/archive/5064/84727/local-6";
                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });


                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });


               mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,Uri.parse("http://stream6.infotraxsys.com/conference/archive/5064/84727/local-6"));

                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//I got this exception


3-18 17:11:15.947  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ native_setup
03-18 17:11:15.947  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
03-18 17:11:15.947  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
03-18 17:11:16.502  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
03-18 17:11:16.502  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
03-18 17:11:18.447  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong I/MediaPlayer﹕ path is null
03-18 17:11:18.452  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
03-18 17:11:18.462  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong E/MediaPlayer﹕ Unable to to create media player
03-18 17:11:26.432  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
03-18 17:11:26.437  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
03-18 17:11:26.442  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1160)
03-18 17:11:26.452  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1131)
03-18 17:11:26.452  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:964)
03-18 17:11:26.457  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:895)
03-18 17:11:26.462  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:105)
03-18 17:11:26.467  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
03-18 17:11:26.472  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17356)
03-18 17:11:26.477  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-18 17:11:26.482  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-18 17:11:26.487  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 17:11:26.492  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
03-18 17:11:26.497  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 17:11:26.507  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 17:11:26.507  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-18 17:11:26.512  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-18 17:11:26.517  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 17:13:10.892  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-18 17:13:10.892  16703-16703/com.example.XXXXXXX.playsong W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: please check the url. its not pointing to an audio file.

Comment: I checked in web browser song is playing

Comment: But this seems, at least to me, to be an open stream and not a reference to a file. In order to play it using built-in `MediaPlayer`, you need to reach the file directly via http or https protocol.

Comment: you can see in log there is message path is null

Comment: Then how can i play this file please help me